# Getting Travel Devotion as a Ruby Knight Vindicator?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, feat-qualifications

The *Travel Devotion* feat (Complete Champion, p. 62) is recommend for most melee builds: moving as a *Swift Action* allows positioning one's character before unleashing a *Full Attack*.

The *Ruby Knight Vindicator* class  (Tome of Battle, p. 122) is an *Initiator* class (and therefore a melee class) and requires *Wee Jas* as a patron deity.

Furthermore, at level 7th, the *Ruby Knight Vindicator* class gains the *Divine Impetus (Su)* class feature, allowing a character to expend one *Turn or Rebuke Undead* attempt to gain one additional *Swift Action*.

All in all, this seems like a match in heaven.

---

Unfortunately, getting the *Travel Devotion* feat as a *Ruby Knight Vindicator* seems complicated.

The traditional way for a Cleric-based character to obtain *Domain* feats is to trade one<sup>1</sup> of their domains for the equivalent *Domain* feat; *Wee Jas*, however, offers neither *Celerity*<sup>2</sup> nor *Travel* as her domains<sup>3</sup>.

Since this trade does not appear possible, this leaves the possibility to select *Travel Devotion* as a feat like other classes do. However, even when selecting feats, a Cleric is still bound to the list of *Domains* offered by their deity<sup>4</sup> and as noted above *Wee Jas* offers neither the *Celerity* domain nor the *Travel* domain.

**How can a Ruby Knight Vindicator, venerating *Wee Jas*, gain access to the Travel Devotion feat?**

---

<sup>1</sup> *As per **Clerics and Domain Feats** (Complete Champion, p. 53), a Cleric can trade away a* Domain *to obtain a* Domain Feat. *This allows Clerics to have 3* Domain Feats *instead of only 2.*

<sup>2</sup> *As per the table **Domain Equivalencies** (Complete Champion, p. 53), only* Celerity *is equivalent to the* Travel Devotion *feat.*

<sup>3</sup> *Compilation of* Wee Jas *domains, for the curious: Death, Destruction, Inquisition, Law, Magic, Mind, Pride, Repose.*

<sup>4</sup> *As per **Clerics and Domain Feats** (Complete Champion, p. 53):*

> *If you are a Cleric (or any other character class who gains access to a Domain), you can choose any Domain feat corresponding to the list of Domains offered by your deity, even if you do not have access to those particular Domains.*

Comment: As it may influence your decision, has the DM confirmed that activating the supernatural ability divine impetus is a free action? (By default, activating it is *technically* a standard action. Of course, makes the ability largely pointless *unless* the vindicator needs a *second* swift action… like to activate a second domain feat on his turn.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan: It never even occurred to me that it could *not* be a Free Action, to be honest. To answer your exact question though, there is neither character nor DM: I was just evaluating some builds (and build advice) and found a few oversights in the recommendations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears there is a single option (the first) which will not require working together with the DM. Otherwise, I have heard that some DMs are partial to pizzas, beers, or car-washing.

---

#### Extra Domain

Certain classes, such *Seeker of the Misty Isles* (Complete Divine, p. 61) gain the *Travel Domain* as an extra *Domain* even if the deity of the character does not offer it<sup>1</sup>.

There is no restriction in the rules for converting a *Domain*:

> In addition, you can choose to give up access to a *Domain* in exchange for the corresponding domain feat. Doing so allows you to select up to three *Domain* feats, but you cannot prepare *Domain* spells or use the granted power of the sacrificed *Domain*. In essence, you trade in a *Domain* for an extra
> feat slot that you can spend only on a specific *Domain* feat.

Of course, becoming a *Seeker of the Misty Isles* comes with its own restrictions, notably being an *Elf*, which may not fit a particular character.

<sup>1</sup> *This is unlike a* Contemplative *who gains an extra* Domain *from the ones offered by their deity.*

---

#### Conversion

A character not following a specific deity can select *Travel Devotion* as a first *Domain* feat with little restrictions as per **Domain Feats** (Complete Champion, p. 52):

> For characters who do not worship a particular deity, use the following guidelines for which *Domain* feats allow or preclude the selection of others. This should be done in concert with the DM.

and

> If you do not follow any specific deity, your basic system of beliefs should support your *Domain* feat choices. A good rule of thumb is to designate one to three *Domains* (in addition to that corresponding to your first *Domain* feat) that are important to you. These beliefs must also be consistent with your alignment.

Furthermore, the case of converting into a follower of a particular deity is not covered. There is no mention of losing, or having to convert, any pre-existent *Domain* feat when becoming a follower of a deity who does not offer the specific *Domain*.

This is a case of your DM stepping in. Still, following the above, a character could first pick *Travel Devotion*, for example starting with a few levels of *Crusader*, and only afterwards become a *Cleric* of *Wee Jas*.

---

#### No Domain.

Only characters with levels in classes with access to *Domains*, such as *Cleric*, are strictly limited to the *Domains* offered by their deity.

> A *Domain* feat usually corresponds to one of the domains to which a particular deity grants access, or those representing a set of ideals.

Avoiding character classes who gain access to a *Domain* therefore makes it possible to avoid the restriction above, although picking *Travel Devotion* will limit the selection of any other *Domain* feat as per **Domain Feats** (Complete Champion, p. 52):

> You can select a *Domain* feat at any level. Once you have chosen one, however, you cannot select another unless the second fits thematically with the first.

and

> Usually, domain feats go together only if they correspond to the domains offered by the deity you follow.

Obtaining *Turn or Rebuke Undead* to satisfy the *Ruby Knight Vindicator* and *Divine* spellcasting to benefit from its spellcasting progression without gaining access to domains is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

#### Be an heretic.

The *Heretic of the Faith* feat (Power of Faerûn, p. 46) allows, among other things, exchanging any one *Domain* you have access to for one you do not normally have access to.

The first issue is that this a *Forgotten Realms* feat, while *Wee Jas* is a *Greyhawk* deity, so there is a conflict of settings.

Furthermore, taking the feat implies being judged as one of the *False* (Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting, p. 250) in most cases:

> Moreover upon your death you are judged one of the *False* unless your deity specifically intervenes on your behalf with *Kelemvor*. Without the use of the *Miracle* or *Wish* spell, this does not happen unless your heresies are adopted by the deity and the faith as a whole. It is theoretically possible that such intervention could occur long after your death, but such cases are vanishingly rare.

And being judged as one of the False, apart from the eternal torment one soul's endures after death, also has the mechanical consequence described in **The City of Judgment** (Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting, p. 250):

> There is no respite for the *False* unless *Kelemvor* wills it, and in this tenure he has not been known to change his mind. Furthermore once *Kelemvor* has made his judgement, the sould cannot be raised or resurrected without the intervention of a deity (represented by at least the use of a *Miracle* or *Wish* spell), who will almost certainly have to negotiate with *Kelemvor*.

Where the conflict of setting is evident, since both *Wee Jas* (in *Greyhawk*) and *Kelemvor* (in the *Forgotten Realms*) are described as having dominions over funeral rites and the faithless dead. Though given *Wee Jas* fiery temper, maybe being judged by *Kelemvor* is preferable to being brought in front of her as an heretic.

---

#### Adapt the Ruby Knight Vindicator

Toward the end of the *Ruby Knight Vindicator* entry is an **Adaptation** section (Tome of Battle, p. 125):

> Although this prestige class is specific to a single crusader order — the *Ruby Knights of Wee Jas* — you could easily adapt it to crusaders devoted to almost any other deity. For example, the faiths of *Hextor*, *Vecna*, or *St. Cuthbert* could
> easily support secret vindicator organizations.

For example, keeping in with the death theme, *Kelemvor* offers both the *Law* and *Travel* domains. Also, *Kelemvor*'s favored weapon is a *Bastard Sword*, instead of a *Dagger*.

---

*At this point, though, it may well be that* Travel Devotion *is simply not worth the expenditure; especially when considering that* Initiators *have many* Strikes *working off a* Standard Action, *thereby allowing moving and initiating a* Strike.

Comment: If a Greyhawk native got to the Forgotten Realms (not that uncommon), _I believe_ Kelemvor would have no claim over their soul, so Kelemvor could judge them False all he wants but it’s not really any of his business and it’s up to Wee Jas to judge the character. And as a Lawful death goddess, she would doubtlessly take any usurpation of her rights and responsibilities here quite negatively. How she would respond to the actual heresy, though, I don’t know.

Comment: The mystic is a base class from _Dragonlance Campaign Setting_ that gets one domain, and explicitly that domain does not come from their deity. On the other hand, I don't know if the _Complete Champion_ rules for domain swapping apply to non-clerics with domains (but even if not, could be an alternative time you could ask the DM for).

Answer (score 1):

***Note:*** This fine [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133572/8610) covers in detail many methods by which a traditional ruby knight vindicator can acquire the feat Travel Devotion. This reader recommends in particular its Conversion method: the noncleric and future vindicator that hasn't yet taken Wee Jas as a patron deity takes the feat Travel Devotion; later, the same character who's now a cleric takes Wee Jas as his patron deity then enters the prestige class. This method allows the character to keep—and use—the feat Travel Devotion throughout his career. However, although it requires negotiating with the DM, there is another relatively easy and largely painless option.

## Ask the DM about a magic item that grants the feat

With the DM's permission, the character may be able to realize the benefit of the feat Travel Devotion (*Complete Champion* 62–3) by acquiring a new magic item that uses the *Arms and Equipment Guide*'s rules for Magic Items that Grant Feats:

> A general guideline for [determining the market price of] other kinds of [items that grant] feats is that they cost 10,000 gp, plus another 5,000 gp to 10,000 gp per prerequisite. (128)

Thus a magic item that grants the wearer the feat Travel Devotion—probably occupying the feet magic item slot—would, by this estimate, typically have a price of 10,000 gp. However, the DM could raise the price to as high as 20,000 gp by ruling that the Travel Devotion feat's domain type is close enough to a prerequisite to count as a prerequisite. Of course, the DM can also place whatever price he wants on such an item. (Also see the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on Variant: New Magic Items (214).)

A DM considering allowing such an item into the campaign should keep in mind that for most creatures a magic item that grants the feat Travel Devotion isn't much better than a *belt of battle* (*Magic Item Compendium* 73) (12,000 gp; 0 lbs.). In fact, in most respects, the *boots of Travel Devotion* are significantly worse.

The *belt of battle* has 3 charges per day, but the wearer can take a swift action to spend 1, 2, or 3 charges to take immediately a move, standard, or full-round action, respectively. The *boots of Travel Devotion*, however, would have for most creatures only 1 charge per day, and a wearer that takes a swift action to activate the *boots* can immediately move up to the wearer's speed and for the next 9 rounds take a swift action only to move up to the wearer's speed.

Turn and rebuke undead attempts can serve as *boot* fuel so that an appropriate wearer can employ the *boots* multiple times per day, but at the levels either item is readily available, an adventurer's workday is usually down to 15 min. anyway, making it so PCs should be able to avoid a second fight in a single day with minimal effort if they so desire.

(The *belt of battle* is used here only for comparison and in the abstract. In truth, this reader believes that the *belt of battle* is generally the most unbalanced magic item published for *D&D 3.5*, and when this reader is DM the *belt* is one of only about 20 specific and unique game elements his house rules outright ban. For instance, after spending 12,000 gp on a *belt of battle*, it's perfectly reasonable for a creature to spend *every subsequent 18,000 gp it earns* incorporating an additional *belt of battle* into its existing *belt of battle*, such is the value of being able to, every turn, take, essentially, *two* turns. (The only *other* magic item the creature may want is one that lets it initiate the 3rd-level martial maneuver White Raven tactics [special] (*ToB* 95).) While this DM thinks that [other](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49573/8610) [magic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64776/8610) [items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61754/8610) can be *even more* unbalanced, those magic items are typically only more unbalanced in the hands of specific creatures, yet the *belt* is unbalanced for *everyone*.)

---

### On Travel Devotion and divine impetus

The feat Travel Devotion may be underwritten for what seems to be the question's goals, as may be the supernatural ability divine impetus of the prestige class ruby knight vindicator (*Tome of Battle* 122–6).

- The benefit of the feat **Travel Devotion** says, in part, that "you can activate this ability to move up to your speed as a swift action each round. Thus, you can move your speed and then take a full-round action, or move and take two." It will be up to the DM to determine if that *each round* language allows a creature that's already realized this benefit once during a round to spend a *second* swift action to move up to its speed *again*.
- The supernatural ability **divine impetus** says, "You can expend a turn or rebuke
  undead attempt to gain one additional swift action this round" (*ToB* 123). While the example is clear about how the ability *should* work—i.e. it allows a creature to take a free action during the round to spend one turn undead attempt to gain one swift action—, the ability is less clear about whether the divine impetus ability can be activated two or more times per round.

  Further, the *Monster Manual* in its Glossary entry on special abilities says, "Using a supernatural ability is a standard action unless noted otherwise" (315), and,  again, while the divine impetus ability in its example strongly *implies* that activating the ability *should* be a free action, the divine impetus ability *isn't* otherwise noted as saying it takes a free action to activate. This—much to the disappointment of LN Wee Jas devotees everywhere, I'm sure—makes activating the supernatural ability divine impetus technically a standard action by default.

To be clear, this reader doesn't completely support either of these strict readings. (He *has* seen these arguments made seriously on forums, though, so they *are* supported by a segment of the player base.) Really, if a PC in this DM's campaign can take multiple swift actions during its turn, this DM would be comfortable allowing the PC to use those swift actions to move up to his speed multiple times if the PC had already realized the benefit of the feat Travel Devotion.

Likewise, this DM is okay with a ruby knight vindicator taking a free action to activate the divine impetus ability. However, this DM *does* make it clear to players who are considering the ruby knight vindicator prestige class that he reads the divine impetus ability being usable only once per round. (That this hasn't hurt the prestige class's popularity is a testament to the power of the supernatural ability divine impetus!)

In short, ask the DM how he reads the abilities instead of assuming they work a certain way.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I agree that an item granting *Travel Devotion* should probably be priced less than a *Belt of Battle*, this is a nice parallel I had not noticed. As for *Divine Impetus*, using *Travel Devotion* is clearly the least powerful use of a *Swift Action* indeed... especially in comparison to all the *Swift* spells a caster can cast (either through *Quicken Spell*, or through *Battle Blessing* should a *Paladin* base be used).

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.